# A problem on Vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra

A text book problem asks if $\Bbb{C}$ is the field of complex numbers, which vectors in $\mathbb{C^3}$ are linear combinations of (1,0,-1) , (0,1,1) and (1,1,1)?

Can it be safely assumed that is talking about a vector space over $\Bbb{C}$ and not over $\Bbb{R}$. How does one go about solving this question?

Comment: From the wording of the question it sure sounds to me like you are supposed to work over $\mathbb{C}$.  I don't know a great way to express the answer other than as the set of all linear combinations (using complex scalars) of those 3 vectors, except I would write that set in obvious set-builder notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1\\
-1 & 1 & 1\end{array} \right) 
\thicksim \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\end{array} \right)$

(you can prove this using the Gaussian elimination method), then

$\det\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1\\
-1 & 1 & 1\end{array} \right) 
=\det\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\end{array} \right) = 1 \neq 0.$

So, these three vectors are linearly independent.

Since they're 3 linearly independent vectors in a 3-dimensional vector space ($\Bbb C^3$ over $\Bbb C$), they generate all $\Bbb C^3$.

On the other hand, if you take $\Bbb C^3$ over $\Bbb R$ (a $6$-dimensional vector space), these three vectors will only generate $\Bbb R^3$, a 3-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb C^3$ over $\Bbb R.$

Comment: I see the linear independence following from the matrix of vectors being able to be reduced to an identity matrix. Just not sure, how it follows from the its determinant being equal to 1 .. won't any unitary matrix would have determinant 1.

Comment: The determinant of the identity matrix is 1.

Comment: Just the fact that the row echelon form is the identity matrix is sufficient to deduce linear independence; the determinant is not necessary to conclude.

Comment: It would be if we want to use the fact that if the determinant of the matrix of a homogeneous system of linear equations is not  $0$, then the only solution of the system is $0$, and that would mean that the column vectors of the matrix are linearly independent.

Comment: @subratverma: Also, the reason why det $A\neq 1$ for all unitary $A$ is because while determinants are preserved by adding rows to one another, they are not preserved by taking scalar multiples of rows. Multiplying a row by $x\neq 0$ divides the determinant by $x$.

Comment: @Twink talking about solution to system of equations, i think we can have a alternate proof: AX = Y where Y is any vector in $\mathbb{C^3}$ and A is the matrix of the three vectors; A is invertible since its equivalent to I. This implies for any vector Y is some linear combination(with complex scalars) of the given three vectors; complex scalars here being the solution to AX=Y